# QGIS plugin : connect to polygonselect Maptool signals

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Working on a new plugin I am trying to connect a custom function to the mouse right-clic signal while using the polygon selecting maptool.

I have activated the maptool through :

```
def run(self):
    self.iface.actionSelectPolygon().trigger()
```

And would now like to connect my selectSite function to a canvasReleaseEvent or similar signal. From an interesting tutorial [here](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html) I adapted the code and tried the line below which failed :

```
def run(self):
    self.iface.actionSelectPolygon().trigger()
    result = QObject.connect(self.canvas.mapTool(), SIGNAL("canvasReleaseEvent()"), self.selectSite)

def selectSite(self):
    QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "in selectSite function" )
```

Is there another way around by connecting to a more generic Qt mouse click signal ?

Any ideas or hints on how I can achieve my goal ?

Comment: iface.mapCanvas() is a QgsMapCanvas and it always generate events. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for helping Luigi. It would be great if the QgsMapCanvas had a "canvasReleaseEvent" Signal like QgsMapTool but I don't see it in the API. Do you know a way of connecting to such a signal ? Although there is a mapCanvasRefreshed Signal I could use as a workaround.

Comment: are you shure? QgsMapCanvas is a QGraphicView (as in documentation) that has release event. And in the qgsmapcanvas.h and in cpp code it is implemented:
http://qgis.org/api/qgsmapcanvas_8h_source.html#l00506 and http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a942107ce7074a40f629b16d4269180a6

Comment: @LuigiPirelli There is indeed a keyReleased event working with QKeyEvent, but no "clicReleaseEvent" or so working with QMouseEvent. It seems from http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/4.8/qkeyevent.html the first one is only related to keyboard.